# Flash Builder - Customizing comboBox

Tags: combobox, flash-builder

I'm populating items to a comboBox from an xml file. I'm trying to customize the font-color of each item that appears in the comboBox. Any suggestions?

Thanks!
--Moe

Comment: Please make sure that you mention the version (Flex 3 or Flex 4) as there is a difference in `Halo` and `Spark` components.

Answer (score 0):

The process is simple if you are using Flash Builder. Each item in your ComboBox is made of an ItemRenderer. Create a custom item render (file - > new -> mxml component) extending that basic ItemRenderer class then assign this new ItemRenderer to your ComboBox. Now inside your custom ItemRenderer you can change values, font sizes, etc ...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an `ItemRenderer`. Though you have not mentioned but it seems you are using Flex 3. The way of using `ItemRenderer` is slightly different in Flex 3 vs Flex 4. So here is the version for Flex 3:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <mx:XMLList id="statesXMLList" xmlns="">
        <state abbrev="AK" name="Alaska" />
        <state abbrev="AZ" name="Arizona" />
        <state abbrev="AR" name="Arkansas" />
        <state abbrev="CA" name="California" />
        <state abbrev="CO" name="Colorado" />
        <state abbrev="CT" name="Connecticut" />
    </mx:XMLList>
    <mx:ComboBox id="comboBox"
                 prompt="Please select a State..."
                 dataProvider="{statesXMLList}"
                 rowCount="3"
                 labelField="@name"
                 itemRenderer="ComboBoxItemRenderer"
                 />
</mx:Application>
```

The class for `ItemRenderer` is `ComboBoxItemRenderer` which is shown below:

```
<mx:VBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            override public function set data(value:Object):void
            {
                super.data = value;
                lbl.text = value.@name;
                if(value.@abbrev == "AK") {
                    lbl.setStyle("color","#FF0000");
                } 
                else if(value.@abbrev == "AR") {
                    lbl.setStyle("color","#FF00FF");
                } 
                else {
                    lbl.setStyle("color","#000000");
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Label id="lbl"/>
</mx:VBox>
```

Do not forget the last `if` (default case) whenever you override `set data` method.